# How do you print the result of a String function in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This is my code:

```
String formatMinute() {
    if (int.parse('${_time.minute}') < 10) {
      String newMin = '${_time.minute}' + '0';
      return newMin;
    }
  }
```

I would like the result of formatMinute() to be in a statefulWidget. Here is my code in the statefulWidget.

```
Text('Time selected: ${_time.hour}:${_time.minute}'),
```

I would like "${_time.minute}" to be replaced with the result of formatMinute(). Is this possible?
Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart, you can put any code including function calls inside string interpolation. So this is perfectly valid:

```
Text('Time selected: ${_time.hour}:${formatMinute()}')
```

Also note that formatMinute implementation could simplified:

```
String formatMinute() => _time.minute.padLeft(2, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try using an extension method! 
(https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)

Keep in mind that 
`TimeOfDay _time = new TimeOfDay.now()` will have the properties `hour` and `minute` as int, so your extension method should also be on an int:

```dart
extension NumberFormat on int {
  String formatMinute() {
    if (this < 10) {
      String newMin = '0' + this.toString();
      return newMin;
    }
    return this.toString();
  }
}
```

And then, this should go inside your widget:

```
Text('Time selected: ${_time.hour}:${_time.minute.formatMinute()}')
```

Notice that the extension method is something like a class, so you need to declare it outside your widget class.

You should update your pubspec to remove any warning too:

```
 environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: This a dart native feature, you don't have to import anything. @Mason

Comment: I uploaded an example main.dart here: https://gist.github.com/EdYuTo/7cf2f24b1fb1caefaffa3b1f714ccd5d

Comment: Here is [my code](https://gist.github.com/MasonTheCoolGuy/3db6238e14efb39110c66b26b1a63782).
For some reason, there is an error saying ```The method 'formatMinute' isn't defined for the class 'int'.``` This is only specific to my coding, not yours. Do you know why? If you don't, that's fine. Thank you **so** much for helping me.

Comment: just updated my answer with a quick explanation. Also, you don't need to import my custom 'Time' class, that was just an example. But I hope it works now, @Mason